# Get gsub and pipe return replacement instead of whole string

Tags: r, magrittr

I want to use `%>%` and `gsub` to write a function which replaces more than one pattern in a string. But instead of returning the string with replaced character, it returns only the replacement:

```
> x <- 'abcdef'
> x %>% gsub('c', ' ')
[1] " "
```

Why is it not returning `'ab def'` in this case?

How can I correctly combine `%>%` and `gsub`?

Comment: thats happening because the `%<%` is passing x to be the first argument. so your gsub call is actually `gsub(x,'c',' ')`.  this can be avoided by not using the pipe if your use case is this simple or by naming your arguments

Comment: As described in `?%>%`: "The _default_ behavior of `%>%` when multiple arguments are required in the `rhs` call, is to place `lhs` as the _first_ argument [...] Often you will want `lhs` to the `rhs` call at _another_ position than the first. For this purpose you can _use the dot (`.`) as placeholder_"

Answer (score 2):

Two options:
naming the parameters:

```
x %>% gsub(pattern = 'c', replacement = ' ')
```

Or using `.` to indicate where the input goes:

```
x %>% gsub('c', ' ', .)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pipes make the following function take by default the left hand side as the first unnamed argument, so to use `gsub` you need to name previous arguments or explicitly show where to place the left hand side in the function call.

That leads you to @YCR's solutions

Many base functions that behave this way (not having the data as the first parameter) have now equivalents in packages such as `purrr` or `stringr`.

If you're going to use `dplyr` and `magrittr` a lot you may want to look for them.

In thiscase you can use `stringr::str_replace_all`

```
library(stringr)
x %>% str_replace_all('c', ' ')
```